# Dynamically set cursor attributes in a-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

How can I set `cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"` dynamically using `setAttribute`
Actually I tried

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').setAttribute('cursor',{rayOrigin:'mouse'});
```

but it just adds cursor attribute to a-scene without `rayOrigin: mouse`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of setAttribute function must be a string, so you should write it like this :
`document.querySelector('a-scene').setAttribute('cursor', "rayOrigin: mouse;");`

Additionally, if you want your cursor to follow the camera, it's better to make it a child of the camera entity instead of setting the attribute on a-scene. You can find an example [here in the documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html).